# Change directory upwards to specified goal

Tags: linux, bash, file-management

I'm often deep inside a directory tree, moving upwards and downwards to perform various tasks. Is there anything more efficient than going 'cd ../../../..'?

I was thinking something along the lines of this: If I'm in /foo/bar/baz/qux/quux/corge/grault and want to go to /foo/bar/baz, I want to do something like 'cdto baz'. I can write some bash script for this, but I'd first like to know if it already exists in some form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that does what you want:

```
cdto () { cd "${PWD%/$1/*}/$1"; }
```

Here's another handy one:

```
c2 () {
        local path num
    if (($# != 0))
    then
        path='./'
    fi
    if [[ -z ${1//.} ]]
    then
        num=${#1}
    elif [[ -z ${1//[[:digit:]]} ]]
    then
        num=$1
    else
        echo "Invalid argument"
        return 1
    fi
    for ((i=0; i<num-1; i++))
    do
        path+='../'
    done
    cd $path
}
```

Usage:

```
c2 .    # same as cd .
c2 ..   # same as cd ..
c2 ...  # same as cd ../..
c2 3    # also same as cd ../..
c2      # same as cd (which is the same as cd ~)
```

I thought one of the shells used to have the cumulative dot-dot-dot feature (I even checked Vista just now and it didn't have it although Google claims that some versions of Windows do).

*Edit*

An undocumented feature of Bash is that a lot of characters are acceptable in function names. As a result, you can do this:

```
.. () { cd ..; }
... () { cd ../..; }
.... () { cd ../../..; }
..... () { cd ../../../..; }
```

Comment: Thanks, the small function you posted is exactly what I asked for, except this: how can I use it as a command in the shell? It works inside a shell script, cd in a shell doesn't affect the pwd of the shell that called it. I tried putting it into an alias, which didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: @haakon: Put the function in a file and source the file using `. filename`. That adds the function to the current environment. You could also simply add the function definition to your `~/.bashrc` file or, like I do, put it in a file with other functions called `~/bin/functions` then in my `~/.bashrc` I have a statement that sources that file `. ~/bin/functions`.

Answer (score 3):

If you often "go somewhere" and then want to "go back" you could use `bash`'s [directory stack](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_73.html): `pushd` to change to the specific directory and `popd` to go back where you came from.

```
[/tmp]$ mkdir -p some/deep/directory/tree
[/tmp]$ pushd some/deep/directory/tree
/tmp/some/deep/directory/tree /tmp

[/tmp/some/deep/directory/tree]$ pushd ..
/tmp/some/deep/directory /tmp/some/deep/directory/tree /tmp

[/tmp/some/deep/directory]$ popd
/tmp/some/deep/directory/tree /tmp

[/tmp/some/deep/directory/tree]$ popd
/tmp

[/tmp]$
```

Otherwise tweak `$CDPATH` as suggested by JRobert.

Comment: Cool solution! I hadn't seen that before.

Answer (score 2):

Make a CDPATH. It does for 'cd' what PATH does for finding executables.  From 'man bash':

> CDPATH The search path for the cd command.  This is a colon-separated list
>                 of directories in which the shell looks for destination directories
>                 specified by the cd command.  A sample value is ".:~:/usr".

Comment: Thanks, I have used CDPATH in the past but it requires planning ahead and having very static paths you want to go to. It's immensely useful in those cases, though.

Answer (score 0):

"cd -" moves back to the directory you were last in.

```
dan@home:/home/dan/ $ cd test/2009/apt/
dan@home:/home/dan/test/2009/apt/ $ cd -
dan@home:/home/dan/ $
```

Comment: I use cd - a whole lot; it's good for when you go back and forwards between two directories. But as soon as you have three or more, it breaks.