# Any shortcut for "cd .."?

Tags: bash, shell, shortcuts

Is there any shortcut for `cd ..`?

Comment: Does it take so long to type?

Comment: YES, it does take too long for something needed that often.

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/147730/change-directory-upwards-to-specified-goal/147785#147785)

Comment: if you're typing it multiple times then you might want to do cd\ which is a shorthand for the more correct cd \ (i.e. cd space backslash)

Comment: @barlop: The question is about `bash`, not about Windows `cmd`.

Comment: Try push and pop

Comment: I'm terribly amused that someone finds `cd ..` too cumbersome to type

Comment: you can make an alias ".."="cd .."

Comment: I suspect the people who need ‘`cd ..`’ so often have the “I must `cd` into a directory before talking about the files there” anti-pattern, rather than specifying filesystem paths.

Comment: @barlop: OT: DOS/Windows' `cd\` goes to the root of top volume (the one with assigned letter), it doesn't go to the parent directory. `cd..` does it and yes, you don't have to type space, so theoretically you save a lot of typing. But, in practice, `cmd.exe` is so rarely used in Windows compared to `/bin/sh` in *nix, that gain is really negligible.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Not by default (There might be some exceptions to this), there isn't. But if you use the `alias` command you can create a shortcut like this:

```
alias ..="cd .."
```

This will allow you to use the command `..` to do `cd ..`.

Comment: Damn, I was just typing the *exact* same thing.

Comment: I'm using also `alias ...="cd ../.."` and two more. Additionally, I can recommend `alias ,=cd "$OLDPWD"`.

Comment: @maaartinus: `cd -`.

Comment: @honk I didn't know it. However, it's too long (and I don't need the output).

Comment: Could someone please explain the downvote?

Comment: The downvote wasn't me, but it could be because some distros do include the alias by default.  I think Ubuntu might, but I'm not 100% sure.  I don't think that warrants a down-vote though.

Comment: @Mark: I upvoted, so I can't answer your question. But anyway, if someone thinks it's bad answer for some reason, he/she is free to downvote. Leaving explanation for downvoting is optional. Of course, it's kind of unethical to downvote competing answers just to get better chances for getting accepted answer.

Comment: @Olli: I know that commenting on downvotes is optional. I just want to know why they thought it was a bad answer, so I can improve on it.

Comment: @Mark: I didn’t downvote either (actually I upvoted), but it could be because they prefer the `autocd` strategy.

Comment: This is standard on zsh

Answer (score 82):

Activate the `autocd` option. It will let you type `..` for `cd ..` and will actually let you use any directory as a command name and will `cd` to it:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

For the curious, the same exists for zsh:

```
setopt auto_cd
```

Comment: That is fantastic.  Time to edit .bashrc on all my linux boxes.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with cygwin bash.

Comment: Woah, that's awesome.

Comment: @gordoco: yeah, it's bash 4.x only. It's the reason why I've been using zsh for 14 years.

Comment: `zsh` (+ `auto_cd`) FTW!

Comment: That's odd, I'm running bash and `shopt -s autocd` doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Why isn't zsh more popular, anyway? All of the cool features bash has been gaining were in zsh first (this, programmable completions...), yet no OS or distro uses zsh as the default shell. Why is that?

Comment: @Mark: I believe this feature only appeared in bash 4.0.

Comment: @SamHocevar: I'm running bash 4.2.0.

Comment: @SamHocevar: I've got it, I just needed to make tmux use the right version of bash.

Comment: @LaC: Technical superiority isn't always a determinant of dominance. Bash is far older and has far more written using it, and practically all shell programmers know it, more than anything else. Change can be hard. -- *from someone who doesn't know what all the zsh noise is all about, and has only really ever used bash* :)

Answer (score 42):

I find this useful:

```
up() { local p= i=${1:-1}; while (( i-- )); do p+=../; done; cd "$p$2" && pwd; }
```

For example, `up 4` = `cd ../../../..`

As a bonus, `` `up 4`/path/to/file `` works in a similar way to `../../../../path/to/file`.

Comment: That's interesting! In 2007 I wrote a similar [function] (http://home.arcor.de/hirnstrom/minis/index.html#up_X) for my .bashrc - file. Your solution allows to jump back the whole way with `cd -` too. Well done! :)

Comment: Nice.  I had something like this for VMS DCL when I worked on that, but didn't really think about it when I moved to Unix and its variants.

Answer (score 16):

After doing a

```
bind '"\eu":"cd ..\C-m"'
```

you can `cd ..` by pressing `Alt-u`.  I used to use this on chdir championships ;-)

If you want the whole swift-chdir suite

```
ALT+u cd ..
ALT+n enter next dir for selection
ALT+p enter previous dir for selection
ALT+SPC choose selected dir
ALT+l list subdirectories and highlight selection
```

just include this in your .bashrc

```
swiftcd-status() {
    echo -n -e "\r\0033[1A\0033[J"
}

swiftcd-contents() {
    find "$swiftcdpath" -maxdepth 1 -executable -type d
}

swiftcd-setdir () 
{ 
    swiftcdpath=$PWD
    swiftcddirnum=1
    swiftcddircount=`swiftcd-contents|wc -l`;
    swiftcd-status
}

swiftcd-pd () 
{ 
    (( --swiftcddirnum <= 0 )) && swiftcddirnum=$swiftcddircount;
    swiftcd-switch $swiftcddirnum
    swiftcd-status
}

swiftcd-updir () 
{ 
    cd ..;
    swiftcd-setdir
}

swiftcd-list () 
{ 
    local redOn="$(echo -e '\0033[31m\0033[1m')"
    local redOff="$(echo -e '\0033[m')"

    swiftcd-status
    ((  swiftcddircount > 1 )) && { 
        echo
        echo $(swiftcd-contents|sed 's!^'"$swiftcdpath"'!!'|sed $swiftcddirnum' s/\(.*\)/'"$redOn"'\1'"$redOff"'/')
    } 
}

swiftcd-nd () 
{ 
    (( ++swiftcddirnum > swiftcddircount )) && swiftcddirnum=1;
    swiftcd-switch $swiftcddirnum
    swiftcd-status
}

swiftcd-switch() {
    (( $1 <= swiftcddircount && $1 > 0 )) && cd $(swiftcd-contents|sed -n $1' p')
}

bind '"\e ":"swiftcd-setdir\C-m"'
bind '"\ep":"swiftcd-pd\C-m"'
bind '"\eu":"swiftcd-updir\C-m"'
bind '"\en":"swiftcd-nd\C-m"'
bind '"\el":"swiftcd-list\C-m"'
swiftcd-setdir
```

Comment: What's a chdir championship? *ignorant*

Comment: Directory navigation sports event.

Answer (score 14):

I use this one since I type too fast and often miss the space bar:

```
alias cd..="cd .."
```

Comment: Most inconvenient for a non-unix person occasionally on a *nix box +1

Comment: s/`non-unix`/`Windows`/

Comment: If you are typing so fast you are missing characters, it's hard to believe adding alias for `cd..` really helps.

Comment: I can see how it could help if you come from dear old DOS, where `cd..` was valid :)

Comment: For some reason I have been typing cd.. a lot for the past week. I thought I was going to have to quit coffee but I like this solution way better.

Answer (score 7):

Try autojump: [autojump on github](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump)

This will not only shorten the cd command into 'j' but also shorten the characters needed for typing the folder you want to jump into.

If you always cd into the folder /home/foo/Projects/thenextfacebook you can just do 'j face' and there you are. It learns automatically which folders are the most important ones for you and after using it for a month now I can say that it is very accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I use `alias …='cd ..'` in my `.bashrc` file. Unicode rules ;)

Answer (score 1):

My bashrc file contains

```
alias ..="cd .. && ls -lG"
```

as well as

```
alias ,,="pushd .. && ls -lG"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Cd Deluxe](http://www.plan10.com/cdd/) for a greatly improved cd command.  It supports things like "cd ..." and "cd ...." and so on in order to quickly navigate upwards.